# jquery validate returning wrong value

Tags: jquery, validation

I have two fields on a form that is used to collect information about a cargo consignment.

Field 1 =  total_pieces
Field 2 = no_of_labels

Both total_pieces and no_of_labels are integers and no_of_labels can be less than but never more than the total_pieces

I have plenty of other fields that are validating correctly but this one is giving me problems.

I started my code with this to work up the validation logic

```
no_of_labels: {"required":function(element){
   return false;                                                        
}}
```

But this allows the field to be blank i.e. just returning false has no effect.

I then tried this

```
no_of_labels: {"required":true, range: [0, $('#total_pieces).val() ]}
```

This worked once and but left the no_of_labels field permanently failing validation

I then consulted the jquery validation documentation and tried this

```
 no_of_labels: {"required":function(element){
    return $("#no_of_labels").val() <= $("#total_pieces").val();                            
 }
}
```

This code had no validation effect on the no_of_labels field

I also added debug:true but nothing displayed in the console.

My final option was using the 'Depend' method

```
 no_of_labels:{required :{
            depends: function(element){

                var labels = parseInt($('#no_of_labels').val());
                var pieces = parseInt($('#total_pieces').val());

                if(labels > pieces){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
            }
          }
```

Still no validation happening.

Can anyone suggest where I'm going wrong?

Here is my full validation code

```
    $("#f1").validate({

       debug:true,
       rules: {

           customer_id: {"required":true},

           total_weight: {"required":true, range: [0, 9999999]},           

           total_pieces: {"required":true, range: [0, 999999]},

           awb_number: {
              require_from_group: [1, ".document_type"]
            },

            house_awb: {
              require_from_group: [1, ".document_type"]
            },

            p_ref: {
              require_from_group: [1, ".document_type"]
            },

           //haulier_name: {"required":true},

           destination: {"required":true},

          // pieces: {"required":true,minlength: 1, maxlength: 5, number: true},

           no_of_labels: {"required":true, range: [0, 100]},

           haulier_name:{required :{
            depends: function(element){

                var ret = $('#spx').val() 

                if(ret != 'Y'){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
            }
          }},

           vehicle_registration:{required :{
            depends: function(element){

                var ret = $('#spx').val() 

                if(ret != 'Y'){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
            }
          }},

           seal_number:{required :{
            depends: function(element){

                var ret = $('#spx').val() 

                if(ret != 'Y'){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
            }
          }},

          driver_name:{required :{
            depends: function(element){

                var ret = $('#spx').val(); 

                if(ret != 'Y'){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
            }
          }},      

           driver_id1:{required :{
            depends: function(element){

                var ret = $('#spx').val() 

                if(ret != 'Y'){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
            }
          }},

           driver_id2:{required :{
            depends: function(element){

                var ret = $('#spx').val() 

                if(ret != 'Y'){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
            }
          }},          

       },
       messages: {
         customer_id: "Customer name required",
         haulier_name: "Haulier name required",
         vehicle_registration: "vehicle registration required if SPX",
         seal_number: "Seal number required if SPX",
         driver_name: "Driver name required if SPX",
         driver_id1: "Driver ID required if SPX",
         driver_id2: "Government ID required if SPX",
         destination: "Destination required",
         pieces:"Pieces required",
         no_of_labels:"Must be less or equal to pieces", 
         awb_number: {require_from_group:"The Master airwaybill, house or p-ref required"},  
         house_awb: {require_from_group:""},  
         p_ref: {require_from_group:""},  

       },
        errorClass: "invalid",
        errorLabelContainer: "#errors"

    });
```

and here is part of the HTML for the field giving me the problems

```
 <div class="row">        
      <div class="col-15">
        <label for="total_pieces">Pieces</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-5">
        <input type="text" id="total_pieces" name="total_pieces" placeholder="Number of pieces" maxlength="6" value ="0">
      </div>


       <div class="col-5">
        <label for="total_weight">Weight</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-5">
        <input type="text" id="total_weight" name="total_weight" placeholder="Estimated weight" maxlength="6" value="0">
      </div>  




       <div id="print_lables">
          <div class="col-10">
            <label for="labels">Labels</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            <input type="text" id="no_of_labels" name="no_of_labels" value ="0" maxlength="3">
          </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please post an example of how your code works

Answer (score 0):

I just did the same thing via a function. It works fine. Instead of return true or false, I made the label Field as empty.

```js
function checkLabels() {
  if (($("#no_of_labels").val()) > ($("#total_pieces").val())) {
    $("#no_of_labels").val('')
  } else {
    alert("Case Success");
  }
}
```

You said "I have plenty of other fields that are validating correctly but this one is giving me problems" Can you post other working validation code with sample HTML you are using so that I can check Further.

Comment: @Malcolmf In your code My final option was using the 'Depend' method

 no_of_labels:{required :{
            depends: function(element){

                var labels = parseInt($('#no_of_labels').val());
                var pieces = parseInt($('#total_pieces').val());

                if(labels > pieces){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    return true;
               }
           }
         }                                                                                                             You sure it has curley Braces }, in end ?

Comment: Even in no_of_labels: {"required":true, range: [0, $('#total_pieces).val() ]} this code you missed ' for ID $('#total_pieces'). You sure everything in correct in your code?